# Facebook doesn't transfer signed_request in IE7

Tags: asp.net, facebook

i have developed a generic facebook app for fan pages. This app can be installed on any page and on each page you see custom content relevant only for this page. In order to do this, i need to receive signed_request from facebook and get fan page id from it. But in some cases in IE7 facebook doesn't transfer signed_request at all(the first load, when one clicks on tab).
I have tried to add headers like:

```
Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

or like:

```
Response.AddHeader("P3P: CP", "CAO PSA OUR HONK");
```

But have so far I do not success to fix it.

Can anyone help me understand why doesn't facebook transfer signed_request in IE7?

Update:

The trick was to update FB.init and add "channel" option to it. in IE7 FB.init without channel will cause reloading of the page and no signed_request in post params.

Answer (score 2):

You got signed_request and parsed it probably. what you can not do is can not read cookies written by `fb jssdk`

so try in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");

}
```